# Execute cmd file on windows deployment server from Jenkins linux server

Tags: jenkins

We have one Jenkins master (Linux) and one Jenkins slave (windows). We are working on .NET Web application. 
Initially our deployment was to prepare the artifacts through TeamCity and invoke a cmd file manually in the deployment server and the deployment happens. The cmd file invoke nant internally and deploy the all required things.

Now we are using Jenkins to implement the CI/CD pipeline.

We have been able to successfully prepare the artifacts and also copied the artifacts to the deployment server through Jenkins. Build and artifact preparation are happening at Jenkins slave.

Pending is , we just need to execute the "cmd" file in the deployment server.

Can anyone please guide me, how to execute the "cmd" file in the deployment server from Jenkins ?
We are using Freestyle project in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

1. First install & configure a Jenkins agent on the deployment server([install](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service), [configure](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows))
2. After selecting your build node: 
   Open the dropdown in the build section and click on Execute Windows Batch Command:

[image: Batch]

After selecting the option, a box will appear to enter the commands.

Comment: We have already jenkins agent installed where build is happening. But we will not install agent on the deployment server (dev,sys,uat,live). Any way to execute the "cmd" file in these deployment server from the jenkins build agent ?

Comment: @ArunJoy "But we will not install agent on the deployment server" why? if you don't do that how can you have access to the deployment server? SHH?

Comment: Hi,is it not possible to execute remote script without installing agents on deployment servers? If we have 5 environments then we have install agents in all the servers ? Can it not be done by executing "psexec" or any other way ?

Comment: This has been done by using shared network path. Providing jenkins build server read/write access to the application server shared path , this has been completed.